# PACT How to test an application when it behaves provider & Consume to fulfil its request

Tags: pact

I have a scenario, where an API(Provider1) consumed by GUI(Consumer1) and at the same time Provider1 Application wants to consume(Consumer2) another API(Provider2) to cater the Consumer1 request. How to test this scenario with PACT.

GUI(Consumer1) -> MicroService (Provider1 & Consumer2) - Another MicroService(Provider2).

Answer (score -1):

I’d read https://docs.pact.io/provider/readme#stub-calls-to-downstream-systems and the gist associated with it. I think it answers your question

Comment: Do you have any example, its all generalised theory

Comment: There is nothing Pact specific here, the approach is to always mock out any external APIs and then write Pact tests between each layer. Keep doing that until you reach the bottom.

Comment: I agree, but my question is more about provider testing, if a consumer request provider then provider depends on another application how do we test it, its more about testing iisolated, as I explained mock consumer works against actual provider if provider depends on another app I think there could be some approach for this

I mean interdependence, and how to solve in pact testing, if your have example it please please provide, it will be better to support it, otherwise its generalised theory

Comment: Provider 1 is also a consumer of Provider 2. So when you are doing a provider verification of Provider 1 (i.e. ensuring it works for Consumer 1(, you can use any mock/stub tools to simulate Provider 2 when doing that test. Think Jest, Mockito etc. Any demo is going to be contextual to your language/framework etc.